# Can I make a virtual function that has a different return based on child?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

In c++, I have a function that returns a map. Depending on the child inheriting this function, the return of the map changes. I am wondering if there is a way to make this function virtual so that I can reduce code reuse and includes.

For a general example, one child function will return a `map<string, int>` and another will return `map<string, bool>`. This is just an example. In my case the map is a string and abstract data type, but the adt changes depending on the child.

I am assuming I simply cannot do this in the way I want. I could instead make an abstract data type to hold my abstract data types, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: It's hard to say based on the little info, but perhaps you should look into templates instead of inheritance.

Comment: The short answer is "no".     In any event, if the function returns a `std::map<string, int>`, it is possible to extract an `int` from the map and covert it to `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using template parent class?

Parent class

```
template < typename T >
class ParentClass
{
public:
    T GetValueByKey(const std::string& key) { /* Get some value from map */}

private:
    std::map < std::string, T > map;
};
```

Child class (int)

```
class ChildClassInt : public ParentClass < int >
{
   /* Do something */
};
```

Child class (bool)

```
class ChildClassBool : public ParentClass < bool >
{
   /* Do something */
};
```